# Show checked="checked" outside foreach

Tags: php, foreach

I have check-boxes that need to show checked, if values of article match up. However i need to now apply that into the check-box html, but i cant wrap the input inside the foreach as it wont work for what i need.

How do i put the checked value inside the html without wrapping it inside the foreach?

PHP:

```
<?php 

foreach($searchRows as $searchRow) { 

    if ($article->id==$searchRow->aid) {
        $true = 'checked="checked"';
    } 
} 

?>
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" <?php echo $true;?>/>
```

The above code is showing every checkbox is checked. I only want the matching values to only be checked.

Cheers
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is correct but first you have to define the value of `$true` blank if you not do this once your if condition matches after that every time `$true` remains `'checked="checkexd"'`.

Use this code

```
<?php 

$true = '';   //Define first blank the variable

foreach($searchRows as $searchRow) { 

if($article->id==$searchRow->aid){

$true = 'checked="checked"';

} } 

?>

<input type="checkbox" <?php echo $true;?>/>
```

Comment: if for any article `$article->id==$searchRow->aid` satifies then the rest of the checkbox also be checked??

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be working fine. Can you think of when this might break?

Answer (score 1):

Store the in an array the print them accordingly -

```
foreach($searchRows as $searchRow) { 
  if($article->id==$searchRow->aid){
    $true[$article->id] = 'checked="checked"';
  } else {
    $true[$article->id] = '';
  } 
}
```

And in the input -

```
<input type="checkbox" <?php echo $true[$articleId];?>/> // Something like this
```

If you are printing checkboxes for article.